# Replace or edit picture in PowerPoint 2013 keeping formatting

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I need to do some (small) changes on some images (PNG) in the PPTX document.

I don't see any option to edit images. If I use the "Change Picture" option to load an edited version of the Picture file, the new picture is inserted instead of the old one, but the size and crop settings are not retained.

The pictures are not linked, so I can not use the Update function (which otherwise works fine).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: From what I can tell, it retains the size of the image when you 'change picture' if that's all you have changed, but if you also have a crop applied, it will scale the image to the cropped shape. It's not right, but I can't see a way around it. Short of making these adjustments outside of Powerpoint, if you have a solid background colour you could always play with using a solid coloured box, without outline (eg. white box, white background) and create your own clipping mask. This then doesn't reset the image size below when you change it as they are independent of each other.

Comment: You can't. Probably it is our fault to depend on the built-in picture editor that lacks such a crucial feature. So I only recommend inserting ready cropped and resized pictures rather than cropping and resizing them within PowerPoint.